# Full row forms with div based tables and turbo frames?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, turbolinks

I have tables structured from DIVs (using Tailwind):

[image]

I am adding inline editing - essential replacing the `table-row` which is wrapped in a `<turbo-frame>` with a form and the intent was to maintain the layout:

[image]

Except the form / turbo-frame breaks the table row structure for the new form elements.  I tried applying the `table-row` CSS to the form but that doesn't work.  I think there must be a simple CSS trick here but I am stumped.

Here is a JSFiddle of the code for both pictured here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jasper502/apyf08kx/22/

I will note that in reality there is some extra Rails Turbo frame elements in here - I have stripped them and will start with getting this plain HTML to work first.  I will sort out the CSS to make the form cells look right after the row are sorted out.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the form is being treated like a table cell.